# Why is bytearray not a Sequence in Python 2?

Tags: python, arrays, python-internals, abc

I'm seeing a weird discrepancy in behavior between Python 2 and 3.

In Python 3 things seem to work fine:

```
Python 3.5.0rc2 (v3.5.0rc2:cc15d736d860, Aug 25 2015, 04:45:41) [MSC v.1900 32 b
it (Intel)] on win32
>>> from collections import Sequence
>>> isinstance(bytearray(b"56"), Sequence)
True
```

But not in Python 2:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi
n32
>>> from collections import Sequence
>>> isinstance(bytearray("56"), Sequence)
False
```

The results seem to be consistent across minor releases of both Python 2.x and 3.x. Is this a known bug? Is it a bug at all? Is there any logic behind this difference?

I am actually more worried about the C API function [`PySequence_Check`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Check) properly identifying an object of type `PyByteArray_Type` as exposing the sequence protocol, which by looking at the source code it seems like it should, but any insight into this whole thing is very welcome.

Comment: You can find your answer in [PEP 3137 -- Immutable Bytes and Mutable Buffer](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) and [PEP 3119 -- Introducing Abstract Base Classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/)

Comment: According to [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#overloading-isinstance-and-issubclass) the expression `issubclass(bytearray, MutableSequence)` evaluates to true... but that's not the case in python2.  AFAIK `PySequence_Check` will return the correct result simply because it does *not* use the metaclass to see whether a class is a sequence. It sees if the field of the `struct` that contains the sequence methods is set or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Abstract classes from `collections` use [`ABCMeta.register(subclass)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) to

> Register *subclass* as a “virtual subclass” of this ABC.

In Python 3 `issubclass(bytearray, Sequence)` returns `True` because `bytearray` is explicitly registered as a subclass of `ByteString` (which is derived from `Sequence`) and `MutableSequence`. See the relevant part of [*Lib/_collections_abc.py*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b76346142b49/Lib/_collections_abc.py#l870):

```
class ByteString(Sequence):

    """This unifies bytes and bytearray.

    XXX Should add all their methods.
    """

    __slots__ = ()

ByteString.register(bytes)
ByteString.register(bytearray)
...
MutableSequence.register(bytearray)  # Multiply inheriting, see ByteString
```

Python 2 doesn't do that (from [*Lib/_abcoll.py*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.10/Lib/_abcoll.py#l631)):

```
Sequence.register(tuple)
Sequence.register(basestring)
Sequence.register(buffer)
Sequence.register(xrange)
...
MutableSequence.register(list)
```

This behaviour was changed in Python 3.0 (in [this commit](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/fe5b2edffae7) specifically):

> Add ABC *ByteString* which unifies *bytes* and *bytearray* (but not *memoryview*).
>   There's no ABC for "PEP 3118 style buffer API objects" because there's no
>   way to recognize these in Python (apart from trying to use *memoryview()*
>   on them).

And there's more information in [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/):

> This is a proposal to add Abstract Base Class (ABC) support to Python
>   3000. It proposes:
>   [...]
>    Specific ABCs for containers and iterators, to be added to the
>      collections module.
>
> Much of the thinking that went into the proposal is not about the
>   specific mechanism of ABCs, as contrasted with Interfaces or Generic
>   Functions (GFs), but about clarifying philosophical issues like "what
>   makes a set", "what makes a mapping" and "what makes a sequence".
>
> [...] a metaclass for use with ABCs that will allow us to add an ABC as a "virtual base class" (not the same concept as in C++) to any class, including to another ABC. This allows the standard library to define ABCs *Sequence* and *MutableSequence* and register these as virtual base classes for built-in types like *basestring*, *tuple* and *list*, so that for example the following conditions are all true: [...] *issubclass(bytearray, MutableSequence)*.

Just FYI `memoryview` was registered as a subclass of `Sequence` only in Python 3.4:

> There's no ducktyping for this due to the *Sequence*/*Mapping* confusion
>   so it's a simple missing explicit registration.

(see [issue18690](http://bugs.python.org/issue18690) for details).

---

[`PySequence_Check`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b76346142b49/Objects/abstract.c#l1375) from Python C API does not rely on the `collections` module:

```
int
PySequence_Check(PyObject *s)
{
    if (PyDict_Check(s))
        return 0;
    return s != NULL && s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence &&
        s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_item != NULL;
}
```

It checks for non-zero `tp_as_sequence` field ([example for `bytearray`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b76346142b49/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#l3116)) and if that succeeds, for non-zero `sq_item` field (which is basically getitem - [example for `bytearray`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b76346142b49/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#l2985)).

Answer (score 4):

When you look at the source code of `collections` abstract classes you will see that in python3 (file `_collections_abc.py`) subclass of `Sequence` class , class `ByteString`, `register` itself with `bytearray` while in python2 (file `_abcoll.py`) there is no `ByteString` class and `Sequence` does not `register` itself with `bytearray`.

By `register` I mean that the abstract class `Sequence` (or it's subclass `ByteString`) is calling [abc.ABCMeta.register](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) method which as said in description of this method *Register subclass as a “virtual subclass” of this ABC.*

I think that is causing differennt behaviour between py2 and py3 but IMHO it's bug (or better fixed bug in py3).